# php imagecreatefrom result is black

Tags: php, gd

I've been trying to figure this out for days. I need to upload an image, have it cropped to a square, resized to 300x300, then resized to 150x150, uploaded into my 'uploads/products/$id/' folder, and then shove the filepath into a mysql database.

However, I keep getting black images outputted. Whats wrong with this script?

```
$ext = explode('.', $_FILES['image1']['name']);
$extension = $ext[1];
$target_path = 'uploads/products/'.$id.'/';
$filename = 'featuredpic.'.$extension;

$featured100_full_path = $target_path.$filename;

if(!is_dir('../../../uploads/products/'.$id)){
    mkdir('../../../uploads/products/'.$id, 0777);
}

if(file_exists('../../../'.$featured100_full_path)) {
    chmod('../../../'.$featured100_full_path, 0755);
    unlink('../../../'.$featured100_full_path);
}

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], '../../../'.$featured100_full_path)){
    echo 'Error: Image Not Uploaded!';
}

if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
    }
else if($extension=="png"){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
} else {
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = 300;
$newheight = 300;
$featured300 = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

$newwidth1 = 150;
$newheight1 = 150;
$featuredthumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1, $newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($featured300,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($featuredthumb,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);

$filename_featured300 = 'uploads/products/'.$id.'/featured300.'.$extension;
$filename_featuredthumb = 'uploads/products/'.$id.'/featuredthumb.'.$extension;

imagejpeg($featured300, '../../../'.$filename_featured300,100);
imagejpeg($featuredthumb, '../../../'.$filename_featuredthumb,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is likely the reason for your black images:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

I'd personally step through each modification process ensuring it's functional and doing something you expect, I have to admit a lot of this code is risky:

```
$ext = explode('.', $_FILES['image1']['name']);
$extension = $ext[1];
```

You place far too much trust in file extensions, this is safer:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

However, I am aware it's an additional PECL extension - so understand why you may have opted for the explode on dot. It's quite difficult to de-bugg your code without writing a wrapper around it for file upload, directory structure...etc

Hint: Keep moving the image to a temp directory with a digit extension, in order for viewing at each phase of the transformation chain - it should quickly identify your flaw! Hope this helps, and sorry I can't be more useful.